# Python: Reading and extracting data from multiples files and writing extracted data in multiple files

Tags: python-2.7

I need to read consecutive 200 files separately with name like nwirp1.rec........nwirp200.rec, then extract data from all the separate file into different consecutive files. I have written code like this. But it is not working.My data is like this

Parameters ----->

Parameter      Estimated value

hklay1         3.278692E-06

kppt1          4.249307E-07

kppt2          2.849132E-06

See file nwirp_nsmc.sen for parameter sensitivities.

I need to extract this portion from each file

hklay1         3.278692E-06

kppt1          4.249307E-07

kppt2          2.849132E-06

and write them on to different output file like data1.txt...........data200.txt

I have tried this way but it is not working:

```
for i in range(1, 200):
    with open('nwirp%s.upw' % i, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip().startswith("Parameter      Estimated value"):
                new_file = []
                line = next(f)
            while not line.strip().startswith("See file"):
                new_file.append(line)
                line = next(f)
            with open('nwirp%s.upw' % i, 'w') as outfile:
                print >>outfile, "".join(new_file)
```

It is showing NameError: name 'new_file' is not defined.

Comment: `if line.strip().startswith("Parameter      Estimated value"):`   ...suppose the `if` isn't true. It skips creating `new_file` (or just as bad, a previous `new_file` list is still there). So its not there in the following loop.

Comment: Are you suggesting me to use try and except method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line match (`f line.strip().startswith("Parameter...`) might not work properly, hence `new_file` doesn't get defined, which probably results in the specified error when you try to append to it or write it down.

Instead of hunting the data line by line, provided that the files are not too large, I'd suggest just simplifying it by using regex to capture the lines between your strings then overwriting the content with the matched lines:

```
import re

matcher = re.compile(r"Estimated value\s+(.*?)\s+See file", re.DOTALL)
for i in xrange(1, 201):  # replace xrange with range when using Python 3.x
    with open("nwirp{}.upw".format(i), "r+") as f:  # open in read-write
        content = matcher.findall(f.read()) # read whole file and grab the match(es?)
        f.seek(0)  # go back to the beginning
        f.write("".join(content)) # concatenate just in case of more matches
        f.truncate()  # remove the extra content
```

That is assuming that you want to **overwrite** to the file you are reading, as expressed in your code, if you want to write to a different file (data1...data200.txt), instead of `f.seek()...f.truncate()` lines use:

```
with open("data{}.txt".format(i), "w") as out:
    out.write("".join(content)) # concatenate just in case of more matches
```

If you don't want to use regex, provided the simple structure of your match, you can achieve a similar effect with `string.find()` to find the first and the last lines' indexes and then get a substring of everything between those two.

Comment: I tried this one but it is not working

import re
matcher = re.compile(r".*?Estimated value\s+(.*?)\s+See file.*", re.DOTALL)
for i in xrange(1, 201):  # replace xrange with range when using Python 3.x
    with open("nwirp{}.upw".format(i), "r+") as f:  # open in read-write
        content = matcher.findall(f.read()) # read whole file and grab the match(es?)
 with open("data{}.txt".format(i), "w") as out:
  out.write("".join(content)) # concatenate just in case of more matches

Comment: Sorry for this crappy comments. I tried to edit this but google chrome is not letting me do edit as I wanted to post as a code

Comment: What's not working about it? Does it throw some error or anything indicating bad operation? Can you post one of your source files somewhere? If the files are named as you say, and their content is as you stated, the above code will most definitely do exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Nothing is happening after command. File is around 5000 lines. I think regex is not working.

Comment: This is working great now! I dont know what happened last time. Thanks for the volunteer support.